How to post process after a Widget/WidgetState loads
I want to run a post process hook after my stateful widget loads.
More concretely, I am building a form using flutter form builder. The form is sometimes prefilled, and if the values are valid I want to enable the submit button. Now, I already have validators on the form itself, and I want to reuse them.
I am trying to do something like the following:
// PostProcess should run after the view first appears and the state of form is built.
void posProcess() {
  if (_formKey.currentState?.isValid) {
    setState(() { _enableSubmit = true })
  }
}


You could check after the first frame is rendered using this code:
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration duration) {
       // here
    });
  }

Also you can use this package : https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout
